# NHibernate id generation - duplicates

Tags: nhibernate, orm, generator

I have a problem with duplicated rows in DB and want to deal with it in a gentle way. I have a NHibernate query that inserts some data into DB (into two tables with relationship). If there is already the row with a specific data in a table I don't want to duplicate it. At the moment there is created a copy with diffrent ID. I've heared that there is a way to generating idenfifiers with NHibernate and then comparing them not to duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to reference existing data where you know the id and don't want to load the record just to save it then there is:

```
var foo = new Foo { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "Bar" };

foo.RefProperty = session.Load<ReferencedClass>(someId);

session.Save(foo);
```